Android 14 Crash: c8.c - TypeError: Cannot read property 'goBack' of undefined, js engine: hermes, stack
I am experiencing a crash when launching the app on Android 14 devices. The crash appears related to the navigation function goBack, which throws a TypeError due to the navigation object being undefined. The issue is specific to Android 14 and occurs when the app launches.
This error seems to be related to how navigation is handled at launch and is further complicated when running in the Hermes JavaScript engine.
Error Message:
com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException
c8.c - TypeError: Cannot read property 'goBack' of undefined, js engine: hermes, stack: anonymous@1:2278959 onPress@1:2302396 onAction@1:289321 __invokeCallback@1:147983 anonymous@1:146226 __guard@1:147094 invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@1:146188
developer_guide

Full Stack Trace:
Fatal Exception: c8.c: Error: Exception in HostFunction: expected 0 arguments, got 1, js engine: hermes, stack:
callNativeSyncHook@1:134985
nonPromiseMethodWrapper@1:132466
NativeReanimated@1:714256
anonymous@1:708209
loadModuleImplementation@1:100717
guardedLoadModule@1:100265
metroRequire@1:99893
anonymous@1:733100
loadModuleImplementation@1:100717
guardedLoadModule@1:100265
metroRequire@1:99893
configureProps@1:865202
anonymous@1:865028
loadModuleImplementation@1:100717
guardedLoadModule@1:100265
metroRequire@1:99893
get@1:943938
anonymous@1:1975249
loadModuleImplementation@1:100717
guardedLoadModule@1:100265
metroRequire@1:99893
anonymous@1:1974841
loadModuleImplementation@1:100717
guardedLoadModule@1:100265
metroRequire@1:99893
anonymous@1:1946337
loadModuleImplementation@1:100717
guardedLoadModule@1:100265
metroRequire@1:99893
anonymous@1:1944287
loadModuleImplementation@1:100717
guardedLoadModule@1:100265
metroRequire@1:99893
anonymous@1:1544444
loadModuleImplementation@1:100717
guardedLoadModule@1:100222
metroRequire@1:99893
anonymous@1:1166405
anonymous@1:1348726
anonymous@1:1348490
trackDerivedFunction@1:1358163
anonymous@1:1379875
useObserver@1:1348349
wrappedComponent@1:1348698
renderWithHooks@1:355785
updateFunctionComponent@1:362065
updateSimpleMemoComponent@1:361523
updateMemoComponent@1:361281
beginWork$1@1:395762
performUnitOfWork@1:383952
workLoopSync@1:383813
renderRootSync@1:383697
performSyncWorkOnRoot@1:381112
flushSyncCallbacks@1:345438
scheduleUpdateOnFiber@1:378251
dispatchSetState@1:359500
tryCallOne@53:15
anonymous@139:26
anonymous@1:233017
_callTimer@1:231963
_callReactNativeMicrotasksPass@1:232128
callReactNativeMicrotasks@1:234113
__callReactNativeMicrotasks@1:135659
anonymous@1:134749
__guard@1:135500
flushedQueue@1:134660
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@1:134603

       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(:75)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(:148)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(:147)
       at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(SourceFile)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage()
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:257)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:368)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(:37)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Occurrences:
The issue is primarily observed on the following devices (percentage of occurrences):
Xiaomi: 25%
Oppo: 21%
Motorola: 18%
Samsung: 18%
What I Tried:
I attempted to navigate back using navigation.goBack() within a functional component, assuming that the navigation object would be initialized as expected. I added checks for navigation being defined, tried using useFocusEffect to ensure that the component is focused, and verified the stack navigation setup.
What Actually Happened:
The app crashes during launch, particularly on Android 14 devices, with the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'goBack' of undefined". Despite adding checks, the issue persists, and it only occurs with Hermes enabled.
